# Using different wallpapers on multiple monitors: Lubuntu with LXQt

Tags: lubuntu, lxqt

I'm using LXQt on Lubuntu 21.10. How could I get a different desktop background on each monitor without having to create one very wide one and stretch it. That is, how can I specify one photo file for each monitor.

Comment: I'll refer you to https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/a-different-wallpaper-in-each-screen/680/2    .... sorry I've not dealt with that in too long to remember how it's easily accomplished (*I don't use it myself*).   When you get it going, feel free to write up an answer (*I'll keep looking for one as I've written one somewhere, sometime*..)

Comment: @guiverc, thanks for the link.  I needed to open it in a private browsing window in order to see it.  Basically it says that this feature is not yet available.  I can wait.  There are many good features in LXQt and Lubuntu.